# Is a miniature Torah scroll considered a real Sefer Torah

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, sefer-torah, games-toys

My son received a [miniature Torah scroll](http://www.google.com/imgres?sa=X&biw=1024&bih=603&tbm=isch&tbnid=2panYJuKQWimFM%3A&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alljewishlinks.com%2Fminiature-torah-scrolls%2F&docid=EDcbkAB56Cji9M&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alljewishlinks.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fimages%2Fall%2F7504-2.jpg&w=275&h=500&ei=Y2kFU4HxDeifyQHTkICAAg&zoom=1&ved=0CH4QhBwwDg&iact=rc&dur=1831&page=1&start=0&ndsp=15) as a reward in Hebrew school.  The letters are not printed clearly and I cannot really read it well, but I would like to know if it should be accorded the respect usually given to a Sefer Torah.  For what its worth, the writing is too smudged for me to find an instance of Hashem's name written on it.  I'd like to hope they would use an abbreviation.

For instance:

I put it on display in our china cabinet, is it now an Aron?

If I say Tachanun in that room, should I put my head down?

If it gets ripped, should it be buried or put into a genizah?

Or possibly, is it not a Sefer and can just be considered a decoration like a Mizrach?

If you think this is too specific (ask your LOR), please rephrase the question.  I am not sure how to ask this in the abstract.

Comment: Related:  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27545/correct-way-to-deal-with-a-damaged-mini-torah?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The miniature Sefer Torah in your link is not a Kosher Sefer Torah. As per [Rabbi Doniel Neustadt](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5765/vayera.html) a non Kosher Torah does not receive the same respect of a Kosher Torah. And it seems to me that he is talking about a Torah that can be Kosher and became non Kosher. You are questioning regarding a Tirah that was never Kosher and is impossible to become Kosher. (It is not on Klaf, It is not written Lishma, Letters are unclear, etc.)

So your Sefer Torah would not make your china closet into an Aron, and not be of assistance when saying Tachanun. However as it has Hashem's name in it and complete Pesukim it should be treated like a Sefer, and not be thrown around, and put into Geniza if torn. http://www.shaimos.org/guidelines.htm